# Is there any resource for showing world territories at different years?

Tags: maps, resource

I teaching a secondary class about a region where the borders were constantly shifting, government constantly changing hands, people within the area changing nationality several times, etc. which is highly confusing to the students. Since it connects with colonialism, I need world maps, not just the local map.

I've tried searching image searches for world maps in year X, but it is hit-or-miss that I find a world map for a particular year, and one map to the next is inconsistent in style.

I need some consistent maps that show where borders changed, when territories changed hands, so students can visually see what they've been reading about.

Is there any resource that allows people to enter in a date, and it displays a world map with colored-in or outlines of the territories?

Comment: For a printed resource, try Colin McEvedy's Penguin Atlas series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_McEvedy

Comment: Seconding @PeterDiehr in general, but what region exactly are we talking about? If its one McEvedy covers well in one of his atlases, we can point you to it. If its not (eg: India or South/Central America), we'll have to find something else (or perhaps just use his modern and recent atlases which have a few pages with world maps specifically to cover colonialisim)

Comment: For this particular class, the focus is the American southwest, so I need to show changes such as the expanding Spanish territory, Mexico's territory, Republic of Texas, French territories, Louisiana Purchase, Mexican Cession, Gadsden Purchase. I prefer to keep things consistent and show a world-wide map, as students really don't have strong geography knowledge and get confused quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://www.timemaps.com

It's pretty much exactly what you seem to be looking for. You can zoom in and out at specific points in time, navigate around the map to different areas, and so forth. The granularity isn't always as precise as one would like now, but in time they'll presumably improve it.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for and I think is shows a sufficient number of dates to show the territorial changes.